# How to prioritize one queue before a funnel

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 2 queues that go into a funnel and then to an InvokeHTTP processor. How can I make sure that there are no flowfiles in Q1 before taking flowfiles from Q2 to go into the funnel?

I've tried with priority attributes but this behavior doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. Both Q's get read from and then after the funnel flowfiles from the high priority get processed first.